# How do i split my html page into two?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps-api-2

Basically i want this two maps to be on the same line.One in the right and the other in the left, but i get one in top and the other in the bottom.
I think that might be achievable with CSS positioning but i am still a beginner at CSS, i divided the two maps with  so that it's more obvious to you guys.

```html
<div>
<iframe
  width="400"
  height="400"
  frameborder="0" style="border:0"
  src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/directions?key=MYAPIKEY&origin=Marrakech+Menara+Airoport+Morocco&destination=Faculté+des+sciences+Marrakech+Morocco&avoid=tolls|highways" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
</div>

<div>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Traffic layer</title>
    <style>
      #map {
        height: 400px;
        width: 400px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 12,
          center: {lat: 31.650456, lng: -8.016392}
        });

        var trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();
        trafficLayer.setMap(map);
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYAPIKEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
</div>
```

Comment: having <div> outside body does not make sense. you can add width:50%; float:left; to make it half page

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/Shreerang/Pp8gT/

Comment: where should i add width:50%; float:left; ??

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
.flex-container{
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
width: 1100px;
height: 550px;
background-color: lightgrey;
}

.flex-item {
background-color: white;
margin: 10px;
}

.item1 {
-webkit-flex: 7;
flex: 7;
}

.item2 {
-webkit-flex: 7;
flex: 7;
}

.item3 {
-webkit-flex: 1;
flex: 1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="flex-container">
<div class="flex-item item1">flex item 1</div>
<div class="flex-item item2">flex item 2</div> 
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Try this for CSS and apply it to your code.